# Android add and remove values from a spinner to a container

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm developing an android aplication and I want to do something like this:

- I want to be able to pick values from a dropdown list (spinner) and add them to a container (like a shopping basket)
- So that way I can be able to add and remove items from the container.

This should work like a form, and at the end, should return a list of items on the "container"

[image: Example]

Comment: what you have did for the same. And where you stuck. Post respective code and tell where is the problem exactly.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia I'm just searching for a solution, I just don't know what can I use to work like a container to store the values.
Because this is like a form, and I pretend to return something like an array with the selected values from the spinner

Comment: you can use spinner or AutocompleteTextView also

Comment: use spinner setAdapter method to change data in it.

Comment: I know how to use a spinner, what I'm looking for, is something to store values that I could pick from the spinner, and then return a list of selected values ​​from the spinner

Answer (score 1):

Use adapters [Spinners | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

[public void add (T object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add%28T%29)

> Added in API level 1
>
> Adds the specified object at the end of the array. Parameters object
>     The object to add at the end of the array.

[public void remove (T object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#remove%28T%29)

> ```
> Added in API level 1
>
> Removes the specified object from the array.
> Parameters
> object    The object to remove.
> ```

After performing `add` or `remove` call [public void notifyDataSetChanged ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

Comment: Using the spinner is not my problem, what I am looking for is a "widget" that can store the values that ​​I choose from the spinner.
Something like the image